# Use a different controller's action for the Index action of the Home Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I think this is a pretty common scenario, but I haven't been able to phrase my problem in such a way that I have generated any useful search engine results. I'd like the `Index` action of my `HomeController` to return the action from a different controller.

I have come up with a few solutions but have dismissed each for various reasons:

- Using a `RedirectToAction` doesn't seem like the right solution as `RedirecToAction` results in an HTTP 303 which for a site's homepage seems wrong.
- Instantiating the other controller and calling its action from within the `HomeController` `Index` action; this option just smells bad.
- Placing the same dependencies as the other controller on the `HomeController` and utilizing the same repository methods. While this is the easiest of the options I've come up with it seems like a cop out.

So, what am I missing here? Does the ASP.NET MVC framework provide a "right" way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using the routing engine for that?

```
routes.MapRoute(
"Special", 
"Home/Index/{id}", 
new { controller = "OtherController", action = "OtherAction", 
id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Remember to put more specific routes before less specific ones.

Regards.

Comment: I am sure this has to do w/ a pattern matching problem: your solution works when explicitly accessing `Home/Index` but doesn't work when just accessing the site's route. Is there a pattern I need to add for that scenario as well?

Comment: @ahsteele I have no means to test it right now, but I´m sure routing is the key for your problem. Try with only "/" (instead of "Home/Index/{id}"). Remember that the order of the routes is important!

Comment: Using a `"/"` causes an `ArgumentException` but just using `""` works great. Thank you!